# Mulitivariable regression?

Tags: regression, correlation, sample-size, multivariable

For my research project on the effect of a specific kind of surgery on clinical outcome,  I want to study the correlation between the improvement in clinical outcome scores (ie the difference between pre-operative and post-operative scores) and the increase of radiological measurements (again, difference between pre-op and post-op measurements). Per patient, 2 types of pre- and post-op measurements have been done. My sample size is very small and consists of only 5 patients. A multivariable regression is probably useless considering the size of my sample. Is there any other way that I could study this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I would divide this into multiple hypotheses:

1. Has there been a change? *t*-tests for pre vs. post: *t*_op, *t*_radio.
2. Is there a correlation between the difference scores (post1 - pre1) x (post2 - pre2)?

   If we in step (1) found that at least one of the scores did not change, carrying on is probably not rewarding. However, we still have not controlled for variables that we think may influence the results. For each variable compute the post score minus the pre score to
   create a difference score, e.g. op_diff = op_post - op_pre.

   Enter the difference scores op_diff,
   radio_diff in the correlation analysis, not the raw data. If you
   need to control for a variable you can perform a partial correlation
   analysis, for example age or gender. Just remember to interpret the
   results in the light of the control.
3. If a variable entering the correlation analysis is ordinal, you need to use Spearman's *rho* instead of Pearson's *r*.

Also, you could use bootstrapping (with 999) for small sample sizes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. All the data are numerical. I've run paired t-tests to check for change and there is a significant difference between pre-op and post-op radiological measurements (in both parameters, height and width). Moreover, there is a significant improvement in clinical outcomne scores between pre-op and post-op. I've used the difference scores in my multivariable regression analysis, but it does not show any significant relationship between improvement in scores and changes in radiological measurements... I'm not familiar with bootstrapping, how could I apply it here?

Comment: Did you try correlating the difference scores as I suggested? Your sample size does not fulfill the assumptions for performing a multilinear regression in the first place. For bootstrapping, there is a chapter in the book Statistical strategies for small sample research, by Rick H. Hoyle, I would recommend.

Comment: What software are you using?